# How to extract all words from tweet using single regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, twitter

I tried below code but this expression finds just one word
please suggest some way to get expected output.

```
import re
tweet = 'RT @marcobonzanini: just an example! :D http://example.com #NLP'
re.findall('(^[a-zA-z]+)\s',tweet)
```

output : ['RT']
expected output =['RT','just','an','example']
so basically remove websites @ mentions,# hash-tags,emotions

Comment: This is not an easy task, at least you have to match URLs and similarly complex entities in order to omit them. Here is an example that gets all whole words starting with letters and omitting some URLs, emails, emoticons - [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/olrbbv/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ghd9RM).

Answer (score 0):

I could match all the cases in your input data by using

```
((RT)|(@[a-z:]*)|(http:\/\/[a-z.]*)|(#[a-zA-Z]*)|( )|(!))|(:D)
```

Here's the live preview: https://regex101.com/r/xKeFOa/1

Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: first of all it gives a string as output, i want tokens   and  i want a genric expression which can which can extract only word and ignore everything else, so no need to specify every thing which needs to be ignored like this tweet : "|ΔΓ|*Take Every Breath God Gives You For What It's Worth.*|*Loving @TheyCallMeBieb since 12-25-12♡*| " you need to modify regex and add things to be ignored , thanks for help :D